# Soldify modifier leaves gap instead of thickness?

Tags: faces

Hey so I'm trying to make eyebrows/eyelashes andnfollow tutorials but when I try to add a solidify modifier it doesn't make it thicker but it leaves a gap. How do i fix this? Thank you!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that mesh contains faces? It looks like it's just edges and verts.

Comment: Ohh i just added a plane, merged it at senter and drew the outsite of the eyerbrow with points (idk theb proper name). How do I add faces?

Comment: The proper name for the points is 'vertices', which is a term from geometry. They're often just called 'verts' for short, though.

Comment: Your solution worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your mesh is just vertices and edges, the solidify modifier faithfully maintains the lack of faces. Therefore you will likely want to use 'Grid Fill' to fill in the shape with quads, or manually do so by selecting three connected edges on your loop and pressing 'f' to fill them in with a face (automatically creating the edge necessary to form a closed shape) and then repeating that process with using the new edge. Note that grid fill requires there to be an even number of verts, so try adding a new one if it causes an issue.